# MinGW gdb ignoring breakpoints when used with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to set up a Windows 7 machine with Eclipse CDT (Kepler) and MinGW. Here follow the steps I perfomed:

1. I downloaded and installed MinGW from the official repository
2. I downloaded and installed the latest (Kepler) Eclipse CDT from the official website
3. I updated the `PATH` global variable so as to include the MinGW bin path `C:\MinGW\bin`. The `PATH` variable is also correctly set in the `Environment` section in Eclipse.

However, when I try to debug (in debug mode) a simple Hello World program, breakpoints are ignored and the execution continues until the end. I tried the following workarounds without success:

- adding the following linker flags: `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`
- manually specifying the binary parser (`PE Windows Parser`)
- change the preferred launcher to `Standard: create process launcher`
- adding the following lines at the beginning of the `main` function: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`

Any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that my program's console output messed up gdb's console output, which is parsed by Eclipse.

The solution was to tell gdb to allocate a new console for the program output, by adding "`set new-console on`" to your .gdbinit file (Make also sure the .gdbinit file is specified under "Debugger options" in Eclipse).

There's also a discussion about this here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327766